# Comma after extension

Tags: regex, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I have problem, I have that string in mediawiki arrays:

```
lorem (ipsum, dolor).jpg, lorem (ipsum) (dolor).JPG, lorem.png
```

and i want find comma after extension, my regex like that:

```
/(jpg|png|bmp|jpeg),/i
```

template:

```
{{#arraydefine:f|lorem (ipsum, dolor).jpg, lorem (ipsum) (dolor).JPG, lorem.png|/(jpg{{!}}png{{!}}bmp{{!}}jpeg),/i}}
{{#arrayprint:f|$}}
```

but don't work, anyone know what is problem?

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Arrays

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work? You forgot `/g` because you want to find *all* commas?

Comment: Maybe [`/(png|bmp|jpe?g),?/ig`](https://regex101.com/r/bJ4jZ9/1)

Comment: No, I using mediawiki arrays and I want find comma but doesn't work. In arrayprint my commas aren't replaced with $

Comment: Are you replacing with `$` with a regex? Then, you most likely must use `$$`. Please try.

Comment: http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/User:Misher/test   - extensions are replaced too

Comment: Did you try escaping `$`? Like `\$`, `\\$` or `\\\$`?

Comment: In arrayprint that doesn't matter and yes I tried it

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found solution, I still don't know why via arrays don't work, but via regex extension work:

```
{{#regex:lorem (ipsum, dolor).jpg, lorem (ipsum) (dolor).JPG, lorem.png|/(png{{!}}bmp{{!}}jp?g),/i| $1 \$ }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done.

Use below regular expression

**/(jpg|png|bmp|jpeg),/ig**